# The $ dollar sign

Tags: jquery

I have something simple like this:

```
$(selector).append("somestuff");
```

But since I'm going to reuse the selector I cache it with:

```
var $selector = $(selector);
```

So I end up with:

```
$selector.append("somestuff");
```

My question is, should I be doing that, or should I be doing:

```
var selector = $(selector);
selector.append("somestuff");
```

Trying either one, both works. Which method is correct, and why?  Is the `$` in `$selector` unnecessary because the jquery object has already been declared in `$(selector)`?

---

#### Edit

Thanks for the answers. It seems very simple and quite clear. Still, there seems to be disagreement over whether or not I should use `$` in the variable. It would be nice for everyone to vote up an answer. :)

Comment: Your question indicates you're a little confused about how objects behave. You might want to review a bit of object oriented programming basics.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I've seen it done both ways.  All you are doing is creating a variable with the name '$selector', so they are functionally equivalent.  The nice thing about it is that it does make them easy to pick out as jQuery objects.

Answer (score 49):

`$` is just a name - names in JavaScript can contain dollar signs, and can consist of just a dollar sign.

Whether you use a dollar sign in your name isn't relevant to jQuery - there's nothing special about the dollar sign, except that jQuery defines a function called `$`.

Comment: I've seen JQuery code with `$j`... is that a JQuery thing or just a custom variable name?

Comment: @Imray: It's common practice to prefix variables which refer to jQuery objects with a dollar sign, eg. `var $highlights = $('div.highlight');`.

Comment: Cool thanks! I never knew that and would've been hard to figure out.

Answer (score 21):

The cash sign is just an alias for the jQuery function. Starting the variable name with $ has no effect on that variable.

It is customary though, especially in jQuery plugin development, to use variables already wrapped in jQuery with a cash sign, so you know you can call jQuery methods, without having to wrap them.

Comment: +1. $ prefix to your variable indicates that it's a jQuery object and you can call all the jQuery methods without thinking whether you need to pass the variable to the jQuery method.

Answer (score 12):

RichieHindle is correct. To expand:

Javascript variables allow the '$' character.  So for example, you could have the following:

```
var $i = 1;
var i = 1;
```

Both i and $i have the same value, and both are perfectly legitimate variable names.

jQuery assigns itself (the jQuery object) to '$' because traditionally, that's what Javascript frameworks have done for selectors.  There's no inherent meaning to '$' beyond what jQuery gives it.

Comment: I think JavaScript frameworks chose `$` for this because most people were not really aware it could be used in variable names so it rarely clashed when introducing frameworks into existing code.

Answer (score 9):

I like to prefix all my jQuery object names with `$` so that I know it's actually a jQuery object, not a DOM reference.

It's a good naming convention.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, `$selector` is an example of Hungarian notation. It is there so that you know that `$selector` is a jQuery object.

If you make it your custom to always have jQuery objects start with `$` if you suddenly use one wrong it will look wrong which will help you find a problem in your code.

The language couldn't care less. They could have just as well named the jQuery function `J` or anything else; the `$` is not a special symbol.

Comment: Of course, strictly speaking, it doesn't let you "know" that `$selector` is a jQuery object; you could just as easily get it wrong and write `var $selector = 0;`. So it's no guarantee.

Comment: OK to be fair it lets you know that $selector *SHOULD* be a jquery object

Answer (score 2):

Yeah.

jQuery always returns a jQuery object. It's what allows chaining.

You've already defined the variable so you get a jQuery object back so $ is unnecessary

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe that you need to add the jQuery selector to jQuery objects (since it's already a part of the object). We don't add the selector and haven't run into any problems.

Comment: It's not "adding the selector".

Answer (score -2):

"$" is a function in jQuery.  So when you call $(selector), you're actually calling the function `$` with `selector` as the argument.

Generally, don't use the "$" as part of a variable name for javascript.  You will only confuse yourself.

Comment: $ is not a function, just an alias. Also, using $ as part of a variable name is a good practice to identify that that variable is a jQuery variable.