# How can I make a javascript variable and use it with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

**How can you make a javascript variable and use it with jQuery?**

I use the following command unsuccessfully in trying to get the POST data out of the var answer. I can access the variable in HTML by $_POST['answer'].

```
var answer = $('#answer').val();
```

I use this variable in this code

```
jQuery('div.answer_' + $answer + ' a.delete_answer')
           .live('click', function(){
```

Comment: FYI.  Javascript != jquery.  jQuery is a javascript framework with functionality to manipulate the DOM.  Javascript is the language in which jQuery is written.  The variable would be a *javascript* variable, not a *jQuery* variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing:

```
var $answer = $('#answer').val();
```

You have a '$' in your selector. You would have to remove the '$' in the selector if you don't want a $ in your variable.

See this:

[The $ dollar sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180213/jquery-the-dollarsign)