# $ vs. jQuery: Which should I use?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the diffrence between them? Which is better?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery: The $ dollarsign](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180213/jquery-the-dollarsign)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`$` is an alias for `jQuery`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L890), neither is "better" really, `jQuery` is provided in case something *else* is using `$`, like Prototype (or [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) was called for another reason...).

I prefer `$` for brevity because I *know* it refers to `jQuery`, if you're unsure (like when writing a plugin) use `jQuery` for your primary reference, for example:

```
(function($) {
  //inside here $ means jQuery
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: So, without prototype is it the same?

Comment: @Diego - yup, unless you call `jQuery.noConflict()`, which releases `window.$` and sets it to whatever it was before.

Comment: @Diego - They reference the same function so long as nothing else has overwritten `$` (i.e. `window.$`) following load and execution of the jQuery script

Answer (score 1):

The functionality is identical if there is no conflict.

Use 'jQuery' instead of '$' to be especially explicit/descriptive, or if you currently use or anticipate using another library that defines '$'.

See also http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery` == `$` == `window.jQuery` == `window.$`

jQuery and $ are defined in window, and $ can be used if no other library is making use of it, thus creating conflicts.

Either use `jQuery.noConflict()` or closures:

```
(function ($) {
    // code with $ here
})(jQuery)
```