# How does Jquery use the dollar sign?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the meaning of "$" sign in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150381/what-is-the-meaning-of-sign-in-javascript)

If Jquery is just external javascript code, then how does it use the dollar sign? Wouldn't that be adding new syntax?

Answer (score 14):

`$` is just a normal variable. You can do `var $ = 42;`.

Comment: I didn't realize you could use dollar signs in defining variables though... I thought they had to start with a letter or underscore and could only contain letters, numbers, and underscores.

Comment: You can use `$` sign pretty much anywhere in a variable name.

Comment: @user828584: Don't worry, yours was a [very](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180213/jquery-the-dollarsign) [common](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846585/can-someone-explain-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript) [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign).

Answer (score 2):

jQuery - and any other javascript framework, simply encapsulate existing functionality in different utility functions. Most platforms endeavor to cover different browser implementations.

So, jQuery's dollar-sign operator is simply a function in which javascript functionality is encapsulated. It is, in essence, an alias for `document.getElementById`, but it also covers getting by class name or tag name.

As for adding new syntax, in short: no, it does not. The look and organization of code written in a framework may be different, but at the core you're still writing javascript, you're just using a set of functions provided by the library instead of using the set of functions in javascript core.

```
var $ = function () {
  // do something here
}
```

Comment: jQuery can also accept callback function - $(fn)

Comment: ...? jQuery's `$` function can accept a large variety of arguments, but I am not certain how that is relevant.