# What does $ mean in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I recently came across a piece of code. It is as follows:

```
      var myFeature = {

'config' : { 
    'container' : $('#myFeature')
},

'init' : function(config) { 

    if (config && typeof(config) == 'object') {
        $.extend(myFeature.config, config);
    }

    myFeature.$container = myFeature.config.container;

    myFeature.$sections = myFeature.$container.
        find('ul.sections > li'); 

    myFeature.$section_nav = $('<ul/>').
        attr('id','section_nav').
        prependTo(myFeature.$container);

    myFeature.$item_nav = $('<ul/>').
        attr('id','item_nav').
        insertAfter(myFeature.$section_nav);

    myFeature.$content = $('<div/>').
        attr('id','content').
        insertAfter(myFeature.$item_nav);

    myFeature.buildSectionNav(myFeature.$sections);
    myFeature.$section_nav.find('li:first').click();

    myFeature.$container.find('ul.sections').hide();

    myFeature.initialized = true;

},


'buildSectionNav' : function($sections) {

    $sections.each(function() {

        var $section = $(this);

        $('<li/>').
            text($section.find('h2:first').text()).
            appendTo(myFeature.$section_nav).
            data('section', $section).
            click(myFeature.showSection);
    });

},

'buildItemNav' : function($items) {

    $items.each(function() {
        var $item = $(this);

        $('<li/>').
            text($item.find('h3:first').text()).
            appendTo(myFeature.$item_nav).
            data('item', $item).
            click(myFeature.showContentItem);

    });

},

'showSection' : function() { 

    var $li = $(this);

    myFeature.$item_nav.empty();
    myFeature.$content.empty();

    var $section = $li.data('section');

    $li.addClass('current').
        siblings().removeClass('current');

    var $items = $section.find('ul li');

    myFeature.buildItemNav($items);

    myFeature.$item_nav.find('li:first').click();

},

'showContentItem' : function() {

    var $li = $(this);

    $li.addClass('current').
        siblings().removeClass('current');

    var $item = $li.data('item');

    myFeature.$content.html($item.html());

}

 };
```

I know what $('#myFeature'), $(this) means. 
But what does $li and myFeature.$container mean? 
Are they some type of variables? 
If so, what is the scope of myFeature.$container? since it is not declared using var, is it global?

Comment: `$` is a char, so its just a var name combination

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Jquery use the dollar sign?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083340/how-does-jquery-use-the-dollar-sign)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is just commons variables, $ is authorized to be part of a var name and the author just like to name his vars with a $ at start. Regarding myFeature.$container this is just a property of the myFeature object so it's the same scope of myFeature

Comment: So, is the myFeature.$container variable like fields in a JAVA class, which has class-level scope ?

Comment: this is more a like a property of the myFeature object, with a public visibility don't know how to explain that in java

Answer (score 10):

`$li` and `$container` are just variable names, named like that so the programmer knows they are jQuery extended objects.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's just a simple variable name.
I do the same with variables which contain jquery objects to quickly distinguish them from my other (non-jquery) vars.

Answer (score 2):

While using a framework like jQuery it is often so that the programmer puts $ signs in front of a variable name so that he knows that the content is a jQuery object.

So for example when you bind a click event and inside the function you have the variable `this` available. But `this` refers to the dom element and not to the jquery object.

So for example you could use something like this to recognize the value of a variable:

```
var $this = $(this);

$this.doSomeJquery();
```

Answer (score 2):

It just allows you to identify the jQuery variables easily from JavaScript variables.

For example:

```
var $section = $li.data('section'); //jQuery variable
var num = 2; //JavaScript variable
```

Can be useful if you have a lot of code with JavaScript and jQuery variables.

See [here for more info.](http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2009/09/jquery-and-how-to-declare-variables.html)

Comment: Thanks. But could you give me more info about myFeature.$container variable?

Comment: Its just a property of `myFeature`, where `$container` references the jQuery object ` $('#myFeature')`. If it was pure JavaScript you would omit the `$` as you wouldn't be working with a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

The dollar sign ($) is an alias for "JQuery"

I mean that

```
$(document).ready(function(){



});
```

is like write:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){



});
```

Edit: I miss interpreted the question, sorry.

Yes, are variables name

Comment: but that wasn't his question ;)

Comment: I miss interpreted the question, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's just some code convention to indicate that it's a variable containing a Jquery object (instead of a DOM object).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the JQuery source (http://bit.ly/jqsource) - right at the end, you'll see:

```
// Expose jQuery to the global object
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

Its just a reference to `window.jQuery`.