# javascript dont work with jquery in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem with my code, which is a mix of jquery and plain javascript.  I use jquery to show and hide some `div`s and the js to refresh a `div` by loading a page inside the `div`. The plain js code doesn't work as is, but if I delete the jquery code it works fine.

My code :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Ton plans</title>
<link href="template/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
    $('#refresh').fadeOut().load('last_post.php').fadeIn();
}, 10000); 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  //no conflict jquery
  jQuery.noConflict();
  //jquery stuff
  (function($) {
      $(document).ready(function()
      {  


         $("#bott_div").click(function() {
         $("#div_profile").show(['fast'])

         })

         $("#page").click(function() {
         $("#div_profile").hide(['fast'])

         })


      })  
 })    
          (jQuery);

</script>

</head>
```

There is a conflict between the jQuery code and the plain javaScript that is preventing it from working properly.  I would require help identifying the problem.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: the question isn't clear, what exactly does "javascript doesn't work with jQuery" even mean? since jquery is a javascript lib

Comment: ( var auto_refresh .... ) not work but if i delete ( (function($) {
      $(document).ready(function()
      {  ...... ) work fine

Answer (score 3):

Change the order of the first two scripts -- like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
    $('#refresh').fadeOut().load('last_post.php').fadeIn();
}, 10000); 
</script>
```

Comment: nothing the js code not work . ( auto_refresh ) but if i delete the jqury code the show and hide . js code work fine

Comment: @SchyzoPhrény - then you must already be including jQuery -- is this part of another service that is already including it (eg typepad)?

Answer (score -1):

There is a "(" in front of your function in jQuery code. Encapsulate code in a

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("sampleSelect").click(function() {
        //code
        }
     });
```

Comment: not always: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403266/understanding-vs-jquery-in-iife-instead-of

Comment: That is how it is supposed to be... it is (....)(jQuery); -- call that code with jQuery as a parameter.