# (function($){ // Some code })(jQuery);

Tags: jquery

What does the following code structure do?

```
(function($){
   // Some code
})(jQuery);
```

I've encountered this structure [here](https://github.com/alex/django-ajax-validation/blob/master/ajax_validation/media/ajax_validation/js/jquery-ajax-validation.js).

### Edit

As a reference to myself:

`jQuery` is the same as `$` in your jQuery scope. Other libraries than jQuery often have the character `$` defined as well. Someone [might want to use another js library next to jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)(e.g. Mootools). In order to let them work together you should undefine or redefine `$`.

*The following line undefines `$` in jQuery:*

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

*The following line redefines `$` as `$jq` in jQuery:*

```
var $js = jQuery.noConflict();
```

When you use the code structure `(function($){ // Some code })(jQuery);` you are guaranteeing the jQuery code `//Some code` to work even is someone called that code in a scope where `$` is undefined.

Also see Tats_innit's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403266/understanding-vs-jquery-in-iife-instead-of).

Comment: THis is for compatibility, to avoid using the `$` and leave it free for other frameworks

Comment: self-invoking function. within this block of code, `$` with represent jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for compatibility, to avoid that [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/) uses the `$` and, by doing so, leave it free for other frameworks.

This function uses jQuery as parameter, so inside the function's scope the `$` will have jQuery's methods that you can call by the `$` (dollar sign).

[**Mootools**](http://mootools.net/) and Prototype use also the dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

It will run some functions when your page is loaded into the browser.

Hope you already refered **[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)**, if not start here [`How jQuery Works`](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)