# jQuery $ Variable Differences

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between these two methods of establishing a variable?

**JavaSript**

```
var img = $('#redImage');
```

**jQuery**

```
var $img = $('#redImage');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [The $ dollar sign](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180213/the-dollar-sign)

Comment: Your headings are a bit odd. Both those examples are JavaScript and both depend on the jQuery library (or another function named `$` that expects the first argument to be a string containing a CSS selector).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The have different names (one of them starts with a `$` sign, the other does not). That is all. The `$` has no special meaning, it is just a character.

Some people use variables starting with a `$` as a hint that the variable is expected to have a jQuery object assigned to it. This is much like the [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) style of prefixing variable names with letters to indicate the type.

Answer (score 2):

`$` in `var $img` is just a naming convention to signify that the variable is a jQuery object

While Doing this -

```
var img = $('#redImage');
var $img = $('#redImage');
```

You actually defined two variables with different **name** -  `img` and `$img`

Answer (score 1):

One creates a variable named img and the other creates a variable name $img ...  The dollar sign is a perfectly valid character in a variable name.

[Valid Characters in Javascript Variable Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names)